# hibernate.QueryException when converting a query

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

I have a HQL query that I'm trying to execute, but I keep getting a QueryException.

My query is

```
SELECT a FROM (SELECT MAX(m.version) maxVersionOp, m.codoperacion codOp FROM ConsumoMe m WHERE m.codoperacion  IN ('MEL101','MEL102') AND m.horizontetemporal IN('PM') GROUP BY m.codoperacion), ConsumoMe a WHERE codOp = a.codoperacion AND maxVersionOp = a.version AND a.fechaBajaLogica IS NULL
```

And the exception I get:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: in expected: SELECT [SELECT a FROM (SELECT MAX(m.version) maxVersionOp, m.codoperacion codOp FROM es.enagas.siomprog.entities.ConsumoMe m WHERE m.codoperacion  IN ('MEL101','MEL102') AND m.horizontetemporal IN('PM') GROUP BY m.codoperacion), es.enagas.siomprog.entities.ConsumoMe a WHERE codOp = a.codoperacion AND maxVersionOp = a.version AND a.fechaBajaLogica IS NULL]
```

If I cut the inner select and try executing it:

```
SELECT MAX(m.version) maxVersionOp, m.codoperacion codOp FROM ConsumoMe m WHERE m.horizontetemporal IN('PM') AND (m.codoperacion = 'MEL101' OR m.codoperacion = 'MEL102') GROUP BY m.codoperacion
```

Then I get a similar exception:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: , expected in SELECT [SELECT MAX(m.version) maxVersionOp, m.codoperacion codOp FROM es.enagas.siomprog.entities.ConsumoMe m WHERE m.horizontetemporal IN('PM') AND (m.codoperacion = 'MEL101' OR m.codoperacion = 'MEL102') GROUP BY m.codoperacion]
```

If I run the SQL equivalent queries, I get valid results. Furthermore, those error messages ", expected in SELECT" are not very helpful.
Any idea of what could be the problem?

Comment: XYZ expected means that the HQL parser was expecting XYZ but got something else. It was expecting 'in' in the first query and ',' in the 2nd one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-subqueries

Hibernate doesn't allow subqueries in the from clause.

Answer (score 1):

I see multiple errors in the SQL

`m.codoperacion codOp` --> `m.codoperacion as codOp`

`AND m.horizontetemporal IN('PM') AND GROUP BY m.codoperacion` --> there should not be AND

```
AND m.horizontetemporal IN('PM') GROUP BY m.codoperacion
```

Comment: also `MAX(m.version) maxVersionOp` --> `MAX(m.version) AS maxVersionOp`

Comment: Thanks, "AND GROUP" was wrong, I pasted the wrong version of the query. About adding "as", it's not necessary, can be omitted. But still, removing that AND does not solve the problem.